# Map domain to a subdirectory of another domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, mapping, subdomain, subdirectory

Our main site (www.example.com) is hosted internally on IIS/ASP.NET servers but we've recently created a blog, which is hosted externally on a Linux/Apache configuration (www.exampleblog.com).

At the moment, we've managed to map the blog to a subdomain of our main site (blog.example.com), but we would prefer it to be mapped to a subdirectory (www.example.com/blog) instead.

Is this possible and, if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this depends, but let me consider your blog is been developed on PHP.

Mainly you need to do the following :

1. Install PHP on you Windows box.
2. Configure and active PHP in IIS.
3. Create a folder in you website maybe you call it blog.
4. From the IIS turn this folder to an App.

Well and that's it.

Note: Am not sure what platform you are running in your blog but basically the main idea is to configure the windows box to run the other site and if it is php you would find many examples about that.

Comment: Hi Issa,

Thanks for the reply.

Our blog is running on WordPress, which uses PHP. Would the solution you suggested still be possible with WordPress? Also, does it matter what version of IIS we're running?

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: Hi @DomStapleton yes sure it is, and regarding the IIS it doesn't matter just follow the steps depending on its version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another web server (Apache) behind the blog site, the only way is a redirect from `www.example.com/blog` to the other web server. You can also use a frame containing the blog site (which is located under another address) so the user doesn't see the other address in the address bar of his/her browser.